# Is there a way to get git to work properly from within a dev container using VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, containers, vscode-remote

I am working with `VS Code` and I installed the `Remote Development` extension. I created a `devcontainer` for my Angular application. So far, everything works fine. The **Dockerfile** and the **devcontainer.json** files are pretty simple:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-12
```

**devcontainer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "Angular App",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "settings": { 
        "git.path": "/usr/bin/git",
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "extensions": [
        "angular.ng-template",
        "natewallace.angular2-inline",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    ],
    "forwardPorts": [4200, 9876],
    "mounts": [ ],
    "remoteEnv": { },
    "postCreateCommand": "yarn install",
}
```

Outside of my container, my git path is in the **C:\Program Files\...** directory. Within my container the git path is **/usr/bin/git**, which is why I set the `"git.path"` property up, and I verified this by using the `which git` command inside my container. Of course, none of the git commands work because they always lead to an error.

> fatal: Could not chdir to 'C:/Workspace/my-angular-app': No such file
>   or directory

I could always use the `Remote-Containers: Reopen Locally` command, and once I'm back in Windows (outside the container), my source control lights up with all my diffs and git works just fine. But, if there is a way to get git to work from within the container it would be helpful. I don't want to constantly have to exit the container to identify the diffs as I'm working on changes.

Comment: Apparently, this is something that has to be resolved (and is being resolved) from Docker itself. Follow the chain: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2591

Comment: Update from the above link - this is now resolved as of Docker v2.2.0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, but it was originally a Docker issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2591

Comment: I'm still having this issue with Docker version 20.10.1 and vs code v 1.52.1 on Linux.

Comment: Same, having this problem right now, Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to change the Windows style path to a *nix style path. In this case, instead of C:/Workspace....  try /mnt/c/Workspace...